# SQL server error: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

Again I am here with an error, i have connected my PHP with SQL server from an IP Address and it works properly in my local PC. but when i transfer my source codes to my client PC it gives below error:

**A Database Error Occurred**

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/SAT_POS/system/database/DB_driver.php

### Line Number: 436

but actualy i have included the extension also and set in php.ini, see below:

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

the above two lines are included in the php.ini file and the extension directory is also the default one, see below:

extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

and in CI database code I configured like below :

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones.

Comment: There are lots of reasons your database connection might fail. Does your client machine have permission to access that IP address on that port? Have you checked the appropriate error function (probably [`sqlsrv_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php))?

Comment: yes the client machine have permision to access that IO address on that port, and even if connect system with a local sqlserver database installed in the same machine is also gives the same error!

Comment: @Chris Except we dont see the host name or ip so they are not actually much use to us

Comment: i cannot share my client's IP, but host name MYPOS10\SQLEXPRESS in local server

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the question originally linked to a different image that included a public IP address and port. OP, **changing the image is not enough! You _must_ also change your password on your database server.** Some users (like me) have already seen your database credentials, and high-reputation users can also see the edit history of the question, including the old image.

Comment: @VeerasingamRajeevan, as I mentioned above, what does `sqlsrv_errors()` return?

Comment: it gives error..?

Comment: IMSSP [SQLSTATE] This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )

Comment: @VeerasingamRajeevan, there you go. I suggest doing what the error message suggests.

Comment: @Chris thank you! I have installed the odbc driver11 on windows, and the problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last with the help of the stack genius who commented on this I have done  the work!

Just installed ODBC DRIVER for SQL SERVER on the windows!

Answer (score 2):

You have to pick ONE SQL Server database extension ONLY.

You have also loaded one extension that is compiled for PHP 5.4

```
php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

AND one that is compiled for PHP 5.6

```
php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Pick the ONE extension that matches your currently runnning PHP version

Also did you load the SQLServer client software on your clients PC.

Comment: i tested with only php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll because my php version is 5.6.3.3

Comment: Did you load the SQLServer client software on the clients PC

Comment: Yes the SQL Server client software is loaded in my client pc